# Book reference for electronic occupation of TM

Tags: reference-request

Is there a book I can reference that has a table like this? I can't reference an online source on my thesis and all the pictures I have found online like this don't make their reference explicit.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Common set of oxidation states of transition metals can be found in virtually every inorganic chemistry textbook. The rest is from the periodic table of elements. [Here is one by NIST](https://www.nist.gov/pml/periodic-table-elements). IMO this is generic stuff you don't need to cite at all, but consulting with your supervisor is the way to go.

Comment: Any general chemistry textbook, e.g. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_Chemistry_(OpenSTAX)/06%3A_Electronic_Structure_and_Periodic_Properties_of_Elements/6.4%3A_Electronic_Structure_of_Atoms_(Electron_Configurations)

Comment: I need to cite something since I am not a chemist (and neither are my professors), I need to show something to corroborate what I am saying. Thank you for the links provided, but I don't see a way to cite the first one, or a list of books in the second one I could get.

Comment: You can cite the first two or three inorganic texts here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry/37305#37305 and maybe this as well https://www.amazon.co.uk/Chemistry-Elements-N-Greenwood/dp/0750633654 if you want to go full overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Element Name and Symbol + Atomic Number + Electron Configuration

[*NIST Standard Reference Database 111*](https://www.nist.gov/pml/ground-levels-and-ionization-energies-neutral-atoms) provides an up-to date reference for the electron configuration of neutral atoms in the ground state [[1](https://doi.org/10.18434/t42p4c)] in both [tabulated](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/ie.pl?spectra=H-DS+i&units=1&at_num_out=on&el_name_out=on&shells_out=on&level_out=on&e_out=0&unc_out=on&biblio=on) and [periodic table](https://www.nist.gov/pml/periodic-table-elements) formats.

#### Common Oxidation States

An overview of elements' oxidation numbers is provided in practically every inorganic chemistry textbook. Arguably, the most extensive one is given throughout Greenwood and Earnshaw's *Chemistry of the Elements* [2].

More compressed information is provided in *CRC handbook of chemistry and physics* (*Section 4. Properties of the Elements and Inorganic Compounds*) [3, pp. 4-1 — 4-92].
There is also a periodic table at the end which includes oxidation numbers of the elements in the upper right corner of each cell:

> [image: CRC Handbook PTE]

#### References

1. Kramida, A., Ralchenko, Yu., Reader, J., and NIST ASD Team (2018). *NIST Atomic Spectra Database* (ver. 5.6.1), [Online]. Available: https://physics.nist.gov/asd. National Institute of Standards and Technology, Gaithersburg, MD. DOI: https://doi.org/10.18434/T4W30F
2. Greenwood, N. N.; Earnshaw, A. Chemistry of the Elements, 2nd ed.; *Butterworth-Heinemann: Oxford; Boston,* **1997**. ISBN 978-0-7506-3365-9
3. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data.; *CRC Press*, **2017**; Vol. 97. ISBN 978-1-4987-5429-3